# Collision error in arcade: When I use the arcade.check_for_collision method in python and a collision occurs, it gives an error

Tags: python, sprite, collision, arcade

I am making a snake game, when I want to implement the collision of the snake with the apple, I encounter the following error.
Collision error in arcade: When I use the `arcade.check_for_collision` method in python and a collision occurs, it gives an error:

```py
ValueError: Error trying to get the hit box of a sprite, when no hit box is set.
Please make sure the Sprite.texture is set to a texture before trying to draw or do collision testing.
Alternatively, manually call Sprite.set_hit_box with points for your hitbox.
```

```
import random, arcade
WIDTH_SCREEN = 500
HEIGHT_SCREEN = 500
class Game(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(width=WIDTH_SCREEN, height=HEIGHT_SCREEN, title='Snake')
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.SAND)
        self.snake = Snake()
        self.apple = Apple()
    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.start_render()
        self.snake.draw()
        self.apple.draw_apple()
    def on_update(self, delta_time: float):
        self.snake.move()
        ***if arcade.check_for_collision(self.snake, self.apple):***
            self.snake.eat()
            self.apple = Apple()
            print(self.snake.score)
    def on_key_release(self, key: int, modifiers: int):
        if key == arcade.key.LEFT:
            self.snake.change_x = -1
            self.snake.change_y = 0
        elif key == arcade.key.RIGHT:
            self.snake.change_x = 1
            self.snake.change_y = 0
        elif key == arcade.key.UP:
            self.snake.change_x = 0
            self.snake.change_y = 1
        elif key == arcade.key.DOWN:
            self.snake.change_x = 0
            self.snake.change_y = -1         
class Snake(arcade.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.width = 16
        self.height = 16
        self.change_x = 0   
        self.change_y = 0
        self.center_x = WIDTH_SCREEN // 2
        self.center_y = HEIGHT_SCREEN //2
        self.color = arcade.color.RED
        self.score = 0
        self.speed = 1
    def move(self):
        if self.change_x > 0:
            self.center_x += self.speed
        elif self.change_x < 0:
            self.center_x -= self.speed
        elif self.change_y > 0:
            self.center_y += self.speed
        elif self.change_y < 0:
            self.center_y -= self.speed      
    def eat(self):
        self.score += 1
    def draw(self):
        arcade.draw_rectangle_filled(self.center_x, self.center_y, self.width, self.height, self.color)      
class Apple(arcade.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.radius = 10
        self.center_x = random.randint(0, WIDTH_SCREEN)
        self.center_y = random.randint(0, HEIGHT_SCREEN)
        self.color = arcade.color.YELLOW
    def draw_apple(self):
        arcade.draw_circle_filled(self.center_x, self.center_y, self.radius, self.color)
game_board = Game()
arcade.run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set `width` and `height` properties for `Apple` class too.

```
class Apple(arcade.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.radius = 10
        self.center_x = random.randint(0, WIDTH_SCREEN)
        self.center_y = random.randint(0, HEIGHT_SCREEN)
        self.color = arcade.color.YELLOW
        self.width = 20
        self.height = 20
```

Answer (score 1):

'print(self.snake.score)'
Is not the proper way to display score in a running arcade window.
arcade has a builtin method "arcade.draw_text()".
furthermore this method may not be called inside on_update but you should call it within on_draw.

Comment: Thank you, but this command is written only to test the code

Comment: `arcade.draw_text` has been deprecated, so use the object-oriented `Text` object